# Changing the name of an URL parameter in a rewrite

Tags: .htaccess

I'm wanting to do a 301 redirect. If the URL parameter was the same, I can do this no problem however I can't do it if I want to change the name of the parameter.

Current URL:

> https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/?search=1&search_string=banana&Category=99

Desired URL:

> https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/search/?search=banana

The "Category" parameter is not required but is needed in the example as I would need to strip this, the only relevant query string I need is "search_string"

Here is what I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=1&search_string=([0-9]*)(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /search/?search=%1? [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't like it, I assume as the '?' should be escaped?

Comment: And "it doesn't like it" means what _exactly_ ? Is "it" frustrated now?

Comment: It's an English phrase meaning it doesn't work.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. But also "it doesn't work" is not helpful. What does that mean _exactly_ ? You certainly should be able to give a specific error message. You should be able to describe what actually happens and where you see a difference to what you would expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The `?` is not needed at the end of the Rewrite target path as it already contains one.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=1&search_string=([0-9]*)&category=(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /search/?search=%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

I also added NE (NoEscape) flag to the rule to  unescape the `?` .